# how to update file name dynametically when upload in ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

hi i am using Ionic 4 with angular 7 in my project.

Currently i am facing difficulties on upload image.

[File Transfer](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer) works fine with a static name like:

```
    let options: FileUploadOptions = {
         fileKey: 'file',
         fileName: 'name.jpg',
         headers: {}
         .....
      }
```

it working fine. but i need dynamic name. so i updated accordingly

```
    this.temp_image_name =  new Date().getTime()+'.jpg';
    let options: FileUploadOptions = {
         fileKey: 'file',
         fileName: this.temp_image_name,
         headers: {}
         .....
      }
```

but it not working and file name return empty. have any idea on this issue. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i solved the issue in server side, before save or upload i renamed the file.

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newfilename = time() . '.' . end($temp);
$target_path = $target_path . $newfilename;
```

and return the newfileName to use the name for next use.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the snippet just to be sure that combining a number `getTime()` and a string was ok, but it didn't seem to have any issues:

[image]

You are using a class level variable which may be being affected by something.

Try:

```
let temp_image_name =  new Date().getTime()+'.jpg';
let options: FileUploadOptions = {
     fileKey: 'file',
     fileName: temp_image_name,
     headers: {}
     .....
  }
```

It seems like you should not be using this plugin at all anyway as [it is deprecated](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#deprecated).

Comment: is server side not get the file name and i used the plugin also